# current spotify track in dwm status bar

Tags: text-processing, dwm

I'm trying to get the current track playing in spotify into my dwm status bar. I got to the point where I get the information with this command.

```
enter code heredbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'
```

The result is this:

```
method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.15 reply_serial=2
variant       array [
     dict entry(
        string "mpris:artUrl"
        variant                string "http://open.spotify.com/thumb/45656b0961cba1598d127c3404ad276acb8e961b"
     )
     dict entry(
        string "mpris:length"
        variant                uint64 308000000
     )
     dict entry(
        string "mpris:trackid"
        variant                string "spotify:track:7oGXMMrB78C5tQhumQ2jfZ"
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:album"
        variant                string "Chopin"
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:artist"
        variant                array [
              string "Frederic Chopin"
           ]
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:autoRating"
        variant                double 0.57
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:contentCreated"
        variant                string "2009-01-01T00:00:00"
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:discNumber"
        variant                int32 0
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:title"
        variant                string "Waltz No. 1 in E flat Major, Op. 18"
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:trackNumber"
        variant                int32 8
     )
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:url"
        variant                string "spotify:track:7oGXMMrB78C5tQhumQ2jfZ"
     )
  ]
```

So my question is how I get the dict entry "xesam:artist" and "xesam:title" out of this result so I can put it in my status bar?

Answer (score 4):

This would be so much simpler if it were well formatted JSON, then you could use a tool like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) to intelligently interrogate the data.

It is possible using `awk`, but is dependent on conistent output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" entry\\("; FS="\""}; /artist/ {artist = $4}; /title/ {title = $4} END { print artist": "title}' spotify_output                      
Frederic Chopin: Waltz No. 1 in E flat Major, Op. 18
```

Essentially, the file is broken up by changing the record separator (`RS`) to the various entry blocks (`entry(`), and the fields within those records are delimited by changing the field separator (`FS`) from the default (a space) to the quote marks (`"`) that hold the values you are seeking.

From there it is just pattern matching (eg., `/artist/`).

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the artist and title, I would suggest using `xprop` to get the `_NET_WM_ICON_NAME` property of Spotify.

```
xprop -name "Spotify Free - Linux Preview" _NET_WM_ICON_NAME
```

gives you:

```
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Spotify - Stereophonics – Indian Summer"
```

you can use `cut` to get the part inside quotes:

```
xprop -name "Spotify Free - Linux Preview" _NET_WM_ICON_NAME|\
cut -d "\"" -f 2
```

skip the starting `"Spotify - "` part again using cut:

```
xprop -name "Spotify Free - Linux Preview" _NET_WM_ICON_NAME|\
cut -d "\"" -f 2|cut -b 11-
```

The artist and title are separated by this dash: `–`. Note that it is different than this: `-`

You can use awk to separate the two:

```
xprop -name "Spotify Free - Linux Preview" _NET_WM_ICON_NAME|\
cut -d "\"" -f 2|cut -b 11-|awk -F " – " '{print $1}'
```

gives you the artist: `"Stereophonics"`

```
xprop -name "Spotify Free - Linux Preview" _NET_WM_ICON_NAME|\
cut -d "\"" -f 2|cut -b 11-|awk -F " – " '{print $2}'
```

gives you the title: `"Indian Summer"`

Comment: Or just `awk`: `awk -F'"' '{sub(/Spotify - /,""); print $2}'`... `xprop` is a nice hack, though: upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on [`sp`](https://gist.github.com/wandernauta/6800547) by GitHub user [wandernauta](https://github.com/wandernauta) :

```bash
SP_VERSION="0.1"
SP_DEST="org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify"
SP_PATH="/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2"
SP_MEMB="org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player"

SPOTIFY_METADATA="$(dbus-send                                                 \
 --print-reply                                  `# We need the reply.`       \
 --dest=$SP_DEST                                                             \
 $SP_PATH                                                                    \
 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get                                         \
 string:"$SP_MEMB" string:'Metadata'                                         \
 | grep -Ev "^method"                           `# Ignore the first line.`   \
 | grep -Eo '("(.*)")|(\b[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.]*\b)' `# Filter interesting fiels.`\
 | sed -E '2~2 a|'                              `# Mark odd fields.`         \
 | tr -d '\n'                                   `# Remove all newlines.`     \
 | sed -E 's/\|/\n/g'                           `# Restore newlines.`        \
 | sed -E 's/(xesam:)|(mpris:)//'               `# Remove ns prefixes.`      \
 | sed -E 's/^"//'                              `# Strip leading...`         \
 | sed -E 's/"$//'                              `# ...and trailing quotes.`  \
 | sed -E 's/\"+/|/'                             `# Regard "" as seperator.`  \
 | sed -E 's/ +/ /g'                            `# Merge consecutive spaces.`\
)"

TrackArtist=$(echo "$SPOTIFY_METADATA" | sed -n 's/artist|//p')
TrackTitle=$(echo "$SPOTIFY_METADATA" | sed -n 's/title|//p')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used wmctrl in the following way:

```
wmctrl -lx | grep spotify | cut -c X-
```

where X is some number that works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I installed `playerctl` for this task (and to manage spotify with dwm keys like **META+F8** (toggle play)).

Then one can use it for example like this:

```
status=$(playerctl -p spotify status)
artist=$(playerctl -p spotify metadata artist)
album=$(playerctl -p spotify metadata album)
title=$(playerctl -p spotify metadata title)
length=$(playerctl -p spotify metadata mpris:length | sed 's/.\{6\}$//')
if [[ "$status" == "Playing" ]] ; then status="▶" ; else status="◼" ; fi

echo "$artist/$album/$title [$status] ${length}s"
```

`$length` is a bit more interesting though. The regular value (extracted out of `metadata`) is:

```
'mpris:length': <uint64 379093000>,
```

I found out that the last 6 characters (093000) are not important (?) and the remaining ones are the duration of the song in seconds, hence the `sed`. You can also change this in `minutes:seconds` by using [this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631). I tested it with some sample songs (also longer ones) and it works.
Unfortunately I didn't find a proper source for my assumptions or the remaining chars ..

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon this 6 year-old thread, Probably the best way to do this would be with playerctl. Install it, then paste this into /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc above exec dwm.

```
 while true; do
     playerctl metadata xesam:title > /tmp/SongTitle.tmp
     playerctl metadata xesam:artist > /tmp/SongArtist.tmp
     title=$(< /tmp/SongTitle.tmp)
     artist=$(< /tmp/SongArtist.tmp)

     xsetroot -name "${title}: ${artist}"
     sleep 1s
 done &
```

This will print title: artist in the menu bar.

Comment: Why use temp files?  Why not just say ``title=$(playerctl metadata xesam:title)`` and `artist=$(playerctl metadata xesam:artist)`? But note that [Anonym’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103140/23408#452047) (from 1½ years ago) already suggests using `playerctl` in a very similar way.