# How can I extract the text between two strings in a log file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I think I have a very similar question to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174540/extract-multiple-instances-of-text-between-two-strings) but I see it was closed due to being unclear so I'll create a new question.

I've got a log file that contains one-line entries with multiple details.

For example:

```
Mon Jan 22 12:12:12 2012 foo=blah   foo2=blah2  foo3=Some longer sentence that can contain spaces and numbers   somethingelse=blarg   foo5=abcdefg
Mon Jan 22 12:13:12 2012 foo=blah   foo2=blah3  foo3=another long sentence that could be the same or different that the prior log entry   somethingelse=blarg   foo5=112345abcdefg
Mon Jan 22 12:14:12 2012 foo=blah   foo2=blah2  foo3=Foo923847923874Some longer sentence that can contain spaces and numbers   somethingelse=blarg   foo5=abcdefg
Mon Jan 22 12:15:12 2012 foo=blah   foo2=blah2  foo3=Fooo02394802398402384Some longer sentence that can contain spaces and numbers   somethingelse=blarg   foo5=abcdefg
```

I want to extract just the content value for foo3.  In other words, I want to see everything right after `foo3=` but right before `somethingelse=`

I was thinking I could do something like `grep -oP 'foo3=[\s\S]*somethingelse='`but the regex is too greedy and eventually results in a "Aborted (core dumped) error.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

### Additional notes:

- This log file is large and has 40,000+ lines in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one `foo3` in line

```
sed -n '/foo3=/{s/.*foo3=//;s/\S*=.*//;p}' file.txt
```

Suppress printing any line (`-n` options) exept which pushed by `p`. For lines which consists `foo3=`:

1. Exchange everything before `foo3=` with it included (`.*foo3=`) to nothing (`//`).
2. Remove everything which starts with some(`*`) non-space (`\S`) symbols with `=`.
3. Prints resedue after two substitution (`p`).

Other

```
sed -n 's/.*foo3=\([^=]*\)\s\+\S*=.*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Exchange full line for pattern (`\1`) in parenthesis (`\(...\)`) which consist any symbols exept `=` and lay after `foo3=` and before some (`*`) spaces (`\s`) then some non-spaces with `=` and prints resedue of lines where such substitution has been done only.

Comment: Bingo.  That works.

Comment: If I may be so bold, could you consider explaining the logic of the command (or pointing me to a reference for `sed` expression scripts)? I want to understand what this is doing so I can avoid asking similar questions in the future.

Comment: @mikeserv Nice look. But `/.*foo3=/{s///;s/[^ ]*=.*//;p}`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^foo3=/P;/\n/!s/[^ ]\{1,\}=/\n&/g;D' <infile >outfile
```

You may have to use a literal newline in place of the `n` above, but this will print only the contents between foo3 and foo4.

For faster processing, get more explicit about it:

```
sed '/\n/s/ [^ ]*=.*//p;/\n/!s/foo3=/\n\n&/;D' | grep .
```

Or with an extra `grep` the top can be much faster as well:

```
sed 's/[^ ]\{1,\}=/\n&/g' | grep '^foo3='
```

Comment: That looks promising but the names of the string markers are quite different from one another so I don't think the `[34]` would work.  I'll revise my example above to make that more clear.

Comment: @MikeB - ok, dropped the check for foo4 entirely - it will just sandwich the first occurrence of `foo3=` plus any/all following characters which are not a space between two newlines, the `D`elete up to the first occurring newline, and, when the cycle renews, `P`rint up to the first occurring newline *(if there is one at all)*. nevermind - foo4 can have a space.

Comment: @MikeB - ok, it no longer cares about spaces except that some sequence of not-spaces is followed by an equals sign. Now it tacks a newline on before every occurrence of some sequence of not spaces followed by an = sign, then does the `D`elete as before. It only `P`rints when `foo3=` is at the head of the line - so it will have to do a couple of `D`eletes before getting there, but it won't do the substitution if there's a newline already on the lin.

Comment: I'm getting an error:  `sed: -e expression #1, char 34: Unmatched \{`

Comment: @MikeB - oops - it's because I didn't match it. Now I have done. If you're ever unfortunate enough to get as familiar with `sed` as I have, you'll find you can just tell automatically how it will work without testing, but that also means you might overlook the very simple stuff *(like a missing backslash)* when writing it out.

Comment: Hmm... I suspect that will work.  sed is now churning away at 25% cpu (and has been for the past 10 minutes).  I'll let it do it's thing and report back when it finishes.

Comment: Ooh. That's no good. I can make it *much* faster. Try the bottom one. Add a `100q` or something to its head when testing so you don't get mired just in case. I don't know why the other one would get caught? 10 mins doesn't seem right - not for 40k lines.

Comment: I'm marking @Costas's answer as the "accepted solution" but want to thank you again for your time, efforts, and especially patience.  It was greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeB - that's completely fine with me. It's a good answer - though if you're using anything other than a GNU `sed` you'll want to do some syntax edits in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=foo3\=).*(?=\s*foo4)" file.txt
```

Comment: That captures the type of text (as well as leaving out the marker names - which is great) but still eventually results in `Aborted (core dumped)`.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @MikeB: How about `grep -Po "(?<=foo3\=).*?(?=\s*foo4)" file.txt` ?

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeB Try `grep -oP "foo3=\K[^=]+(?=\b\w+=)" file.txt`

Comment: @Costas Immediately went to error for that one.

Comment: @MikeB Very strange. What kind of error? Try `grep -oP 'foo3=\K[^=]+(?=\s+\S+=)' file.txt` There is no difference with sed' regexp above. What version of `grep` you use? `grep -V`

Comment: @Costas `Aborted (core dumped)`.